# Git remote branch deleted by mistake:any loss of information?

Tags: git, push, bitbucket, git-branch

I have mistakenly issued the following command:

```
git push origin branch1 --delete branch2
```

thinking I could simultaneausly update branch1 and delete branch2. The result was that I deleted both branches from origin. Both of them are however available locally, so what I did afterwards is:

```
git push -u orgin branch1
```

Now branch1 is available in remote. 
My question is: *did I loose any information by deleting and then creating again the remote branch?*

Note:
My bitbucket account reports these operations as

> Changeset stripped from MyUsername/MyRepo

before reporting the new commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends:

1. Yes: If someone who has access to the same repository and pushed any changes to `origin/branch1` then their changes would have been lost.
2. No: If you've had updated `branch1` from `origin/branch1` i.e. remote, before deleting it from remote.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I am the only user of this directory, so nobody had done anything else in the meantime.

Comment: @GioPan : Then be happy. You didn't lose anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

> did I loose any information by deleting and then creating again the remote branch?

Assuming that the local `branch1` was simply ahead of the remote one with the same name, then no, you should not have lost any data.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  `branch1` was ahead of `origin/branch1` by one commit (merged from `branch2`), so `origin/branch1` was deleted and then created again with an additional commit.

Answer (score 0):

That depends, you will have whatever you had up to branch1 locally.
If branch2 was ahead of branch1 then you lose that information, which I'm assuming was not important since you were deleting it.